# Scheme - Passing too much arguments into a function doesn't cause error?

Tags: function, functional-programming, scheme

Given the following code :

```
(define (g x y) (* x y)) 

(define (f x y z)
   (define (h x y)(g (+ x y) x z))h)
```

Notice that I pass `3` arguments into `g` ,where `g` accepts only `2` .

However ,no error message is presented from the interpreter , why ?

Regards

Comment: The absence of error messages is expected when you don't actually *call* anything with wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: But I do call `g`, I call it with `3` parameters ...

Comment: then show a code where you *call* `g`. In your current code, you define something that *would* call `g` if it had a chance.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: Aha ! got it , only when I actually invoke a call to `g` with `3` parameters , then I'd get the expected error ! +1 ! thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't actually calling h here, only returning it. Properly formatted your code should look like:

```
(define (f x y z)
    (define (h x y)
        (g (+ x y) x z))
    h)
```

So when you call (f 1 2 3) you get back h. If you call

```
((f 1 2 3) 1 2)
```

then the interpreter will give an error.